Error while using webdriver from selenium
I was trying webscraping using selenium. I ran this code:
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = "C:\\Users\\winwin\\Documents\\Visual Studio\\chromedriver.exe"
URL = "https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/994662672/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(URL)

But it showed an error:
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
File "C:\Users\winwin\Documents\Visual Studio\Python\ScratchScraping\main.py", line 6, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

What do I do?
I know that I setted up selenium and the webdriver correctly.

Are you using a config file, like a .ini file?

What do you mean?

I've seen this error when a script tries to read from a configuration file.  Is 'capabilities' a variable defined in a configuration file?

What configuration file?

@Larcury check if thid answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/78283461/23421645

The error message "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'" suggests that the code is attempting to access a 'capabilities' attribute on a string object, which obviously does not exist.
This can occur if there's some confusion in how the arguments are being passed to the webdriver.Chrome constructor. Typically, this constructor can take various arguments, but if the arguments are not passed correctly, it might misinterpret a string (like the path) as another type of argument.

@Lakshmanarao Simhadri no, my desktop doesn't have the Automation directory.

@Larcury that's actually a user specific directory. I answered it as per that question. In your case you can use your own directory.

As long as you are using Selenium 4.6+, there is no need to manage your own chromedriver any more because they added Selenium Manager. Your code can now be simplified to
from selenium import webdriver

URL = "https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/994662672/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)


Thank you it works! But I still have a problem, when chrome opened, shortly after it closed.
